# Splitting time from same column and storing into 2 column and finding difference between those 2 columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Splitting time from same column and storing into 2 column and finding difference between those 2 columns in sql server.

```
select SourceName,Active,EventTimeStamp,
case when Active=1
then EventTimeStamp END as ActiveTime,

case when Active=0
then EventTimeStamp END as InactiveTime

from dbo.AllEvent
where SourceName='R2_20'
order by SourceName 
;


sname   active  EventTimeStamp      Active      Inavtive
R2_20       1   14:51.9     14:51.9     NULL
R2_20       0   14:53.9     NULL        14:53.9
R2_20       1   15:05.9     15:05.9     NULL
R2_20       0   15:07.9     NULL        15:07.9
R2_20       1   15:15.9     15:15.9     NULL
R2_20       0   15:17.9     NULL        15:17.9
R2_20       1   15:26.0     15:26.0     NULL
R2_20       0   15:28.0     NULL        15:28.0
R2_20       1   15:36.0     15:36.0     NULL
R2_20       0   15:38.0     NULL        15:38.0
```

Comment: time i had store in start and end column, now i need to find the difference between those 2 column,

Comment: What is your expected output request you to include in question and explain the logic also?

Comment: sname   active  EventTimeStamp      Active      Inavtive
R2_20       1   14:51.9     14:51.9     NULL
R2_20       0   14:53.9     NULL        14:53.9
R2_20       1   15:05.9     15:05.9     NULL
R2_20       0   15:07.9     NULL        15:07.9

see row 1,
14:51.9(active = 1)  should subtract from 14:53.9(inactive =0) and store in diffrence column

Answer (score 3):

If the version of SQL Server you are using supports the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, use it. But this is only my guess based on the data you provided.

```
SELECT
  SourceName sname,
  Active active,
  EventTimeStamp start,
  [end],
  DATEDIFF(millisecond, EventTimeStamp, [end]) difference
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(EventTimeStamp)
      OVER (PARTITION BY SourceName
            ORDER BY EventTimeStamp, Active DESC) [end]
  FROM AllEvents
) t
WHERE Active = 1;
```

But for a more complex data set, the following query may be preferable.

```
WITH
  AllEvents AS (
    SELECT
      sn SourceName,
      CAST(a as INT) Active,
      CAST(ts as TIME) EventTimeStamp
    FROM (VALUES
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:14:51.9'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:14:52.9'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:14:53.9'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:15:05.9'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:07.9'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:15:15.9'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:15:16.9'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:17.5'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:17.9'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:15:26.0'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:28.0'),
      ('R2_20', 1, '00:15:36.0'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:37.0'),
      ('R2_20', 0, '00:15:38.0')
    ) t(sn, a, ts)
  ),
  a AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY EventTimeStamp) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SourceName, Active ORDER BY EventTimeStamp) g
    FROM AllEvents
  ),
  b AS (
    SELECT
      SourceName,
      Active,
      IIF(Active = 0, MAX(EventTimeStamp), MIN(EventTimeStamp)) start
    FROM a
    GROUP BY SourceName, Active, g
  ),
  c AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      LEAD(start) OVER (PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY start, Active DESC) [end],
      DATEDIFF(millisecond,
               start,
               LEAD(start) OVER (PARTITION BY SourceName
                                 ORDER BY start, Active DESC)) difference
    FROM b
  )
SELECT * FROM c WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY start;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, see Eventtimestamp is the time storing same column, based on active and inactive i have to divide in two columns, that i did using what i have posted the code, now with those active and inactive column, i have to find the diffrence, in this case, what is happening is, active(1) is storing some time and in inactive column its storing null, and next line in Active column is storing null and Inactive(0) column is storing time, so i m not able to find the diffrenece between active and inactive